# How to resolve Errors after adding jquery.d.ts to project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

In Visual Studio, I create an default TypeScript site.

I then use Nuget to add jquery.d.ts.

I then compile the app.

The error window shows me 101 Errors in the jquery.d.ts file such as:

```
Error   341 ',' expected.
```

How do I resolve these errors?

Have I incorrectly imported the file, or is there some setting I need to set?

The actual error as shown in the UI says:

```
A parameterized initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
```

On this line:

```
replaceAll(target: JQuery|any[]|Element|string): JQuery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of TypeScript compiler. Union types (that is `JQuery|any[]|Element|string`) are only available since TypeScript 1.4

Try updating TypeScript for Visual Studio.

Comment: I have the same issue, but when using Visual Studio Update 5.  It suggests against manually updating TypeScript and sticking with the version built into Updae 5.